# looping function and receiving bytes in java

Tags: java, loops

```
public class InterfaceGUI implements ActionListener {

private JFrame frame;

private JPanel panelController;
private JPanel panelJack;
private JPanel panelModbus;
private JPanel panelLog;
private JPanel panelStatus;
private JPanel panelToController;
private JPanel panelToJack;

private JLabel lblIpAddController;
private JLabel lblPortController;
private JLabel lblIpAddJack;
private JLabel lblPortJack;
private JLabel lblStatusToController;
private JLabel lblStatusConnToCont;
private JLabel lblIpAddToController;
private JLabel lblIpAddConnToCont;
private JLabel lblPortToController;
private JLabel lblPortConnToCont;
private JLabel lblStatusToJack;
private JLabel lblStatusConnToJack;
private JLabel lblIpAddToJack;
private JLabel lblIpAddConnToJack;
private JLabel lblPortToJack;
private JLabel lblPortConnToJack;
private JLabel lblSlaveId;
private JLabel lblIcon;

private JButton btnConnController;
private JButton btnDiscController;
private JButton btnConnJack;
private JButton btnDiscJack;
private JButton btnConnModbus;

private JTextArea textAreaConnLog;

private JTextField textFieldIpAddController;
private JTextField textFieldPortController;
private JTextField textFieldIpAddJack;
private JTextField textFieldPortJack;
private JTextField textFieldSlaveId;
private Socket myClient;

public byte[] message = new byte[5];
private static final String modbusConn = "modbusconnect";
private static final String modbusDisc = "modbusdisconnect";



/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args){
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                InterfaceGUI window = new InterfaceGUI();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
                //window.receiveMessage();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public InterfaceGUI() {
    initialize();
}

public void startRunning() throws IOException{
    try {
        while (true){
            System.out.println("receive");
            InputStream inFromServer = myClient.getInputStream();
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
            in.read(message);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(message));
        }
    } catch (EOFException eofexception){
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    panelController = new JPanel();
    panelController.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Connection to Controller", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    panelController.setBounds(6, 6, 438, 95);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panelController);
    panelController.setLayout(null);

    lblIpAddController = new JLabel("IP Address :");
    lblIpAddController.setBounds(13, 24, 74, 16);
    panelController.add(lblIpAddController);

    textFieldIpAddController = new JTextField();
    textFieldIpAddController.setBounds(92, 18, 174, 28);
    panelController.add(textFieldIpAddController);
    textFieldIpAddController.setColumns(10);

    btnConnController = new JButton("Connect");
    btnConnController.setBounds(278, 18, 154, 29);
    panelController.add(btnConnController);
    btnConnController.addActionListener(this);

    lblPortController = new JLabel("Port :");
    lblPortController.setBounds(54, 58, 33, 16);
    panelController.add(lblPortController);

    textFieldPortController = new JTextField();
    textFieldPortController.setBounds(92, 52, 174, 28);
    panelController.add(textFieldPortController);
    textFieldPortController.setColumns(10);

    btnDiscController = new JButton("Disconnect");
    btnDiscController.setBounds(278, 52, 154, 29);
    panelController.add(btnDiscController);
    btnDiscController.addActionListener(this);

    panelJack = new JPanel();
    panelJack.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Connection to Jack", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    panelJack.setBounds(6, 113, 289, 95);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panelJack);
    panelJack.setLayout(null);

    lblIpAddJack = new JLabel("IP Address :");
    lblIpAddJack.setBounds(14, 24, 74, 16);
    panelJack.add(lblIpAddJack);

    textFieldIpAddJack = new JTextField();
    textFieldIpAddJack.setBounds(93, 18, 106, 28);
    textFieldIpAddJack.setText("111.111.1.111");
    panelJack.add(textFieldIpAddJack);
    textFieldIpAddJack.setColumns(10);

    btnConnJack = new JButton("Connect");
    btnConnJack.setBounds(200, 20, 86, 29);
    btnConnJack.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panelJack.add(btnConnJack);

    lblPortJack = new JLabel("Port :");
    lblPortJack.setBounds(55, 58, 33, 16);
    panelJack.add(lblPortJack);

    textFieldPortJack = new JTextField();
    textFieldPortJack.setBounds(93, 52, 106, 28);
    panelJack.add(textFieldPortJack);
    textFieldPortJack.setColumns(10);

    btnDiscJack = new JButton("Disconnect");
    btnDiscJack.setBounds(200, 52, 86, 29);
    btnDiscJack.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    panelJack.add(btnDiscJack);

    panelStatus = new JPanel();
    panelStatus.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, null, null), "Connection Status", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    panelStatus.setBounds(6, 220, 438, 126);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panelStatus);
    panelStatus.setLayout(null);

    panelToController = new JPanel();
    panelToController.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Connection to Controller", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    panelToController.setBounds(6, 20, 208, 94);
    panelStatus.add(panelToController);
    panelToController.setLayout(null);

    lblStatusToController = new JLabel("Status");
    lblStatusToController.setBounds(41, 19, 39, 16);
    panelToController.add(lblStatusToController);

    lblStatusConnToCont = new JLabel("DISCONNECTED");
    lblStatusConnToCont.setForeground(Color.RED);
    lblStatusConnToCont.setBounds(85, 19, 117, 16);
    lblStatusConnToCont.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panelToController.add(lblStatusConnToCont);

    lblIpAddToController = new JLabel("IP Address :");
    lblIpAddToController.setBounds(6, 43, 74, 16);
    panelToController.add(lblIpAddToController);

    lblIpAddConnToCont = new JLabel("New label");
    lblIpAddConnToCont.setBounds(113, 43, 61, 16);
    lblIpAddConnToCont.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panelToController.add(lblIpAddConnToCont);

    lblPortToController = new JLabel("Port :");
    lblPortToController.setBounds(47, 66, 33, 16);
    panelToController.add(lblPortToController);

    lblPortConnToCont = new JLabel("New label");
    lblPortConnToCont.setBounds(113, 66, 61, 16);
    lblPortConnToCont.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panelToController.add(lblPortConnToCont);

    panelToJack = new JPanel();
    panelToJack.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, null, null), "Connection to Jack", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    panelToJack.setBounds(218, 20, 214, 94);
    panelStatus.add(panelToJack);
    panelToJack.setLayout(null);

    lblStatusToJack = new JLabel("Status");
    lblStatusToJack.setBounds(41, 19, 39, 16);
    panelToJack.add(lblStatusToJack);

    lblStatusConnToJack = new JLabel("DISCONNECTED");
    lblStatusConnToJack.setForeground(Color.RED);
    lblStatusConnToJack.setBounds(85, 19, 123, 16);
    lblStatusConnToJack.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panelToJack.add(lblStatusConnToJack);

    lblIpAddToJack = new JLabel("IP Address :");
    lblIpAddToJack.setBounds(6, 43, 74, 16);
    panelToJack.add(lblIpAddToJack);

    lblIpAddConnToJack = new JLabel("New label");
    lblIpAddConnToJack.setBounds(116, 43, 61, 16);
    lblIpAddConnToJack.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panelToJack.add(lblIpAddConnToJack);

    lblPortToJack = new JLabel("Port :");
    lblPortToJack.setBounds(47, 66, 33, 16);
    panelToJack.add(lblPortToJack);

    lblPortConnToJack = new JLabel("New label");
    lblPortConnToJack.setBounds(116, 66, 61, 16);
    lblPortConnToJack.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    panelToJack.add(lblPortConnToJack);

    panelModbus = new JPanel();
    panelModbus.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Modbus", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    panelModbus.setBounds(296, 113, 148, 95);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panelModbus);
    panelModbus.setLayout(null);

    lblSlaveId = new JLabel("ID :");
    lblSlaveId.setBounds(33, 24, 22, 16);
    panelModbus.add(lblSlaveId);

    textFieldSlaveId = new JTextField();
    textFieldSlaveId.setBounds(60, 18, 82, 28);
    panelModbus.add(textFieldSlaveId);
    textFieldSlaveId.setColumns(10);

    lblIcon = new JLabel("icon");
    lblIcon.setBounds(17, 52, 32, 35);
    panelModbus.add(lblIcon);
    Image imgDisconnect = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("red-unlock-icon.png")).getImage();
    lblIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgDisconnect));

    btnConnModbus = new JButton("Connect");
    btnConnModbus.setBounds(60, 51, 82, 29);
    panelModbus.add(btnConnModbus);

    panelLog = new JPanel();
    panelLog.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Connection Log", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    panelLog.setBounds(6, 358, 438, 214);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panelLog);
    panelLog.setLayout(null);

    textAreaConnLog = new JTextArea();
    textAreaConnLog.setBounds(6, 19, 426, 189);
    panelLog.add(textAreaConnLog);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(ae.getSource() instanceof JButton){
        if(ae.getSource() == btnConnController){
            //check validity ip dan port number later on
            try {
                myClient = new Socket("192.168.1.104", 1234);
                if(myClient.isConnected() == true){
                    textAreaConnLog.setText("connected to 192.168.1.104 at port 1234");
                    lblStatusConnToJack.setText("CONNECTED");
                    lblStatusConnToJack.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
    }
}
```

}

I am currently building a client program to receive broadcasted message by the server. Just want to make things clear, is it correct that the method startRunning() will keep looping itself without anyone calling it? Also, the incoming data is in the form of bytes, can i use the method .read(message) to read and store the data into message[]?

Answer (score 0):

**Is it correct that the method startRunning() will keep looping itself without anyone calling it?**

You have to call the method startRunning() at least once so that it starts executing its code; after that the while block will continue to loop infinitly unless an exception occurs.

**Also, the incoming data is in the form of bytes, can i use the method .read(message) to read and store the data into message[]?**

Yes, you can. See this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) for the specifications

If I might add a tip:

```
private boolean Continue = true;

public void setContinue(boolean b)
{
     Continue = b;
} 


public void startRunning() throws IOException
{
    DataInputStream in;
    try
     {
        while (Continue)
        {
            System.out.println("receive");
            InputStream inFromServer = myClient.getInputStream();
            in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer);
            in.read(message);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(message));
        }
    } 
    catch (EOFException eofexception)
    {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        in.close();
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Note the condition of the while-loop. This would make your code more responsive to interrupts, should you need them; streams should not be open infinitly.

Also, you ought to close the stream when an exception does occur.